# Difference between .values and .iloc on a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently refactoring some code where I see both these lines being used :

- `foo = df['bar'].values[0]`
- `foo = df['bar'].iloc[0]`

From my current understanding, both lines do the same thing: retrieving the first value of the pandas series.

**Are they really the same?
If yes, is one way more recommended than the other?** (due to internals subtleties, speed, behavior when setting value instead of getting value, etc)

Comment: Using `.values` for any purpose is discouraged in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html?highlight=pandas%20series%20values#pandas.Series.values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `df.values` actually returns a `numpy.array` (i.e. it can be used without square brackets).

```py
df[col].values
df[col].values[0] # 1st element of numpy array
df[col].values[1:3] # 2nd and 3rd element of numpy array
```

Meanwhile `df.iloc` is a position based indexing to get elements from a dataframe. `iloc` must be used with square brackets otherwise you'll see an error.

```py
df.iloc # Error
df.iloc[row, col] # Returns a cell, array (`Series`), matrix (`DataFrame`) based on input
```

The subtle difference lies in the object being returned, and also the implementation behind the scenes.

`iloc` directly reads data from memory and returns the output.

`values` converts a `DataFrame` into a `numpy.array` object and then reads data from memory and returns the output (hence `iloc` is faster).

Comment: `df.iloc` does not raise an error -- it returns an Indexer object.  Also, when I've tested it, `iloc` is always _slower_ than `values`.